# CSS Selector for name attribute of <a>?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

This may be a dumb question, but what is the CSS Selector for the attribute of `<a>` that is "name"?

```
document.body.innerHTML = myString.anchor("HTML_String")
```

This JavaScript creates a `<a>` element with the name `"HTML_String."`
How do I access only this element in my CSS?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "the attribute of <a> that is "name"? in the top line before the code.

Comment: The `name` attribute for anchors has been removed from HTML as of [HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). Put an ID on the element you want to link to instead.

Comment: @Quentin: Huh. So it has. I was under the impression it was simply deprecated. *Edit:* so it turns out when HTML5 says "obsolete" it can mean either "obsolete" or "deprecated" - checker.html5.org says that the name attribute is obsolete but it emits a warning, not an error unlike for things such as presentational attrs.

Answer (score 7):

CSS doesn't have a specific selector syntax for name attributes. You have to use the generic [attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) syntax.

> `[att=val]` Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is exactly "val".

Answer (score 4):

There is the `[name="name"]` selector but it's not really cross-browser. Old versions of Internet Explorer don't support the selector by HTML attribute (that browser tho.........).

My suggestion is to always use `class`es for CSS (even for unique elements) and `id`s for JavaScript, while you'll leave the `name`s for backend programming.

Add a class to the element and then `a.myclass`

Comment: Who uses IE 6 these days though?

Comment: It's supported in IE7 as far AIK who damn cares for a dead browser any more?

Comment: If you want to build a **real** website you should support even the most awful browsers, as long as they respect the HTML and CSS standards.
And as I said, it's better if names are reserved for the backend programming.

Comment: @Quentin - Nobody hopefully, though they might be using IE11 in "compatibility mode".  There are, unfortunately, still corporate legacy apps that require quirks mode.

Answer (score 3):

```
[name="yourName"]
```

or if it only should have any name:

```
[name]
```

an example for an input:

```
input.myClass[name="greatName"] {
    ...
}
```

But if your question is how to look for something within your "innerHTML": This isn't possible.

Answer (score 3):

use the [attribute=value] css selector, you can access it by using :

```
a[name=HTML_STRING] {
  //your css
}
```