# How to call an HTML object with the 'name' tag?

Tags: html, css

Now this might be a dumb question and if so I sincerely apologise for wasting your time.

I was wondering how one was to call an HTML object with the 'name' tag.
Here an example to explain what I mean:

```
HTML: <p id="one"></p>
CSS: #one{}

HTML: <p class="two"></p>
CSS: .two{}

HTML: <p name="three"></p>
CSS: ?
```

I need this because I'm working with commercial JavaScript UI components and they have a naming system based on `name`.

Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: [name="three"] {}

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Comment: Just that you know: It's invalid for a `p` element to have a `name` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select elements by data attribute in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Selector for name attribute of <a>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242296/css-selector-for-name-attribute-of-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```css
[name='three'] {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<p name="three">x</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS attribute selector. `p[name]` css will affect all your `<p></p>` element with `name` attribute.

```css
p[name] {
  background: green
}

p[name="three"] {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<p name="two">text</p>

<p name="three">text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p[name="three"] { color:red }
```

you can select css by attribute tag